# How to build an Ecommerce Shopping Cart in Django?

Tags: python, django, shopping-cart

Is there a book or a tutorial which teaches how to build a shopping cart with django or any other python framework ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a book coming out that talks about just that. See here:

http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430225355

Edit: The above link is dead, so here's a working link for the book: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=LwO1GzMN_QsC

It's called Beginning Django E-Commerce by James McGaw.

Comment: I found this book incredibly helpful.  Thumbs up.

Comment: Although now that I'm further along in it, it gets very complicated very quickly.

Comment: link is dead ... :(

Answer (score 5):

Satchmo project is a known open source shopping cart.
http://www.satchmoproject.com/

Comment: Sadly, despite all the upvotes, this project no longer seems to exist.

Comment: @machineghost That doesn't seem to be the case. Here is a bitbucket link for it: https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/wiki/Home

Comment: If you check the page history, it doesn't look like there have been any updates to that wiki since mid-2014.  Plus, it still links to the project's site (http://www.satchmoproject.com/) ... and that link is still dead.  To be 100% honest, I don't know if the project is completely dead or not, but if the team behind a **web** library can't even handle putting up a single web page at the project's domain name, it's effectively dead in my book (whether or not it actually is).

Answer (score 3):

Ingredients:

- one cup PayPal (or subsitute with other equivalent payment system)
- few cups html
- add css to taste
- add django if desired

Cooking:

- Mix well.
- Bake for 1-2 month.

Release as open source :-)